# Регулярные выражения с захватывающим поиском назад

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть некие строки (каждая строка обрабатывается отдельно!)

```
(икра красная) икра красная, другие слова
о - соль белая (соль белая)
размер соль желтая (соль белая)
```

Требуется удалить дубликат фразы, если оно есть в скобках и тут же рядом без скобок. С первой строкой проблем не возникает https://regex101.com/r/Q5503z/7

```
\((.+?)\)\s*\1 замена на \1
```

Правильно ли я понял, что регуляркой невозможно обработать вторую строку так как \1 еще не существует на момент открытия группирующих скобок?

Можно ли решить другим способом регулярками?

**Необходимо получить:**

```
икра красная, другие слова
о - соль белая
размер соль желтая (соль белая)
```

Comment: удалять нужно только те слова, которые в скобках (и скобки) ?

Comment: если ответ на предыдущий вопрос "да", то нужно заменить обычную ссылку на подмаску `\1` на рекурсивную ссылку на подмаску `(?1)`: [демо](https://regex101.com/r/Q5503z/3)

Comment: Сослаться вперед конечно нельзя. Но никто не мешает ведь в первуг группу включить само слово и искать после него то же слово, но в скобках. (т.е. буквально переставить скобки в вашем выражении

Comment: @Эдуард дописал, что нужно в результате

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая замена, только надо на php переписать:

```js
console.log(
`(икра красная) икра красная, другие слова
о - соль белая (соль белая)
размер соль желтая (соль белая)`
.replace(/(([^()]+).*)\(\2\)|\(([^()]+)\)(.*\3)/gm, "$1$4")
)
```

Comment: получилось то что надо, сенкс, жаль без объяснения, напомните, плиз, что значит `.*` в конструкции `(([^()]+).*)`

Comment: Любое количество любых символов (кроме переводов строк).

Comment: все понял, я привык пользоваться аналогом - `.+?` смотрю работает и вообще с одной точкой `.` в данном конкретном примере.

Comment: `+` - это 1 или более, `*` - это 0 или более.

Comment: да да, я в курсе.